# Stream audio from browser to icecast

Tags: node.js, audio, icecast

I would like to stream live audio from my browser to my icecast server.
So far I managed to record the audio in the browser and store it as a .WAV file.
I was thinking of using a nodejs server to get the audio, but I don't know how to stream the audio to one of the icecast stream clients.

Does anybody knows how to make the link between the nodejs server and the icecast server? (they can both be on the same server).

Comment: If Webcast doesn't meet your needs, I have an alternative solution which has support for many codecs, streaming to multiple servers, and sending the status of that remote connection back to the streaming client.  You can e-mail me at brad@audiopump.co.

Comment: I've managed to stream the audio to the server but I didn't manage to route the incoming stream to iceCast. Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try Webcaster
http://webcast.github.io/

it has an example for NodeJS

Comment: I think this is what I was looking for!
Many thanks!